# What is the name of the :: operator in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, operators, java-8

I can't find the name of the `::` operator added in Java 8 in either of the following resources:

- [Proposed Final Draft Specification: The Java Language Specification (JLS)](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-pfd-spec/java-se-8-jls-pfd-diffs.pdf)
- [JSR-000335 Lambda Expressions for the Java Programming Language Proposed Final Draft](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/lambda-0_9_1-pfd-spec/index.html)

Comment: Maybe _method reference_ operator?

Comment: What does the :: operator do?

Comment: I am not sure it can be considered an operator. After all operators are like functions that act over operands. And what are the operands the `::` operator act upon? I think it is more a syntax feature, like the `[]` or `<>`.

Comment: I found a video tutorial that shows how this works and he calls it a method reference too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwwIZuwYmNI&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa9YGfyhyW2CqdtW9RtY-I3&index=21

Comment: and the next one where using forEach is demonstrated https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfbmYBcq5CM&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTa9YGfyhyW2CqdtW9RtY-I3&index=22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should probably be called a **"colon colon separator"**:

- Brian Goetz* calls it "colon colon" and since he was the specification lead for the lambda JSR I suppose we can consider him as an authoritative source.
- The [specification #3.11](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/se/8/java-se-8-pfd-spec/java-se-8-jls-pfd-diffs.pdf) classifies `::` as a separator.

<sub>**source: [the road to lambda @ Javaone 2013 around 04:00](http://www.parleys.com/share.html#play/5250e2fbe4b0c4f11ec57682).*</sub>

Comment: The video isn't loading for me right now (probably just streaming videos blocked here), but assuming it says that then I would consider that an actual answer. :)

Comment: @280Z28 The video did not work for me on firefox - it does work on Internet Explorer - that's shocking!

Answer (score 7):

As per [here](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/java-far-sight-look-at-jdk-8.html), it *looks* like it's called a method reference operator. It's covered in section 15.13 of the proposed JLS you link to.

However, as rightly pointed out, it appears to be never explicitly named as an operator (unlike all the things like `+`, `-` and so on). Instead, the JLS simply refers to the entire expression containing `::` as a method reference expression.

It may be that this is because `::` is *not* considered to be an operator at all but is explicitly called out as a separator (see JLS link 3.11, while the operators are in 3.12).

So I would tend to call it, in the context you're interested in, a method reference separator (or, more generally, the double-colon separator).

Comment: The link you gave never refers to `::` by name. In addition, section 15.13 never refers to `::` by name. This is in stark contrast to sections 15.14 through 15.26, which section by section give explicit names to each of the other Java operators.

Answer (score 0):

It's described as a 'separator' in both #3.11 and #15.13.3.